# How To Create UpdateView CBV with relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm tired to find the best way for UpdateView with CBV. Im test some tutorial but always got error. Maybe someone can help me.
I have 2 models. Account and UserProfile.
First. I Register Account User Like This, And Extending the user in UserProfile Model.
Thats Success.

[UserProfile models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APoxV.png)

My Question is, how to Update The data ini this field ?

**authentication/models.py**

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
email                   = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
full_name               = models.CharField(max_length=150)
create_account          = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_reviewer             = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)

objects = CustomAccountManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

**dashboard/models.py**

```
class UserProfil(models.Model):
JENIS_KELAMIN_CHOICE = (
    ('Pria', 'Pria'),
    ('Wanita', 'Wanita' ),
)

#Profil
user                    = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
gelar_depan             = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, default="")
gelar_belakang          = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="")
nik                     = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, unique=True, default="")
nidn                    = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, unique=True, default="")
email_alternatif        = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True, default="")
jenis_kelamin           = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, default="", choices =JENIS_KELAMIN_CHOICE)
tempat_lahir            = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, unique=True, default="")
tanggal_lahir           = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
nomor_handphone         = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True)
alamat                  = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="")
```

**dashboard/forms.py**

```
class UserProfilForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model           = UserProfil
    fields          = '__all__'

    widgets = {
        'gelar_depan'       : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'gelarDepan', 'placeholder' : 'Gelar Depan'}),
        'user'              : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'namaLengkap', 'placeholder' : 'Nama Lengkap'}),
        'gelar_belakang'    : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'gelarBelakang', 'placeholder' : 'Gelar Belakang'}),
        'nidn'              : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'nidn', 'placeholder' : 'Nomor Induk Dosen Nasional'}),
        'nik'               : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'nik', 'placeholder' : 'Nomor Induk Karyawan'}),
        'tempat_lahir'      : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'gelarBelakang', 'placeholder' : 'Tempat Lahir'}),
        'tanggal_lahir'     : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'gelarBelakang', 'placeholder' : 'Tanggal Lahir', 'type' : 'date'}),
        'nomor_handphone'   : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'nik', 'placeholder' : 'No Handphone'}),
        'email_alternatif'  : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'emailAlternatif', 'placeholder' : 'Email Alternatif'}),
        'alamat'            : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'alamat', 'placeholder' : 'Alamat'}),
        'jenis_kelamin'     : forms.Select({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'jenisKelamin',}),
    }
```

**dashboard/views.py**

```
class UserProfilUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
model               = UserProfil
form_class          = UserProfilForm
template_name       = 'dashboard/profil.html'
success_url         = '/dashboard/profil'

def form_valid(self, form):
    # form.instance.user  =   self.request.user
    messages.success(self.request, 'Success Save Your Data!.')
    print(self.request.user)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

### EDIT

dashboard/views.py

```
class UserProfilUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
model               = UserProfil
fields              = '__all__'
template_name       = 'dashboard/profil.html'
queryset            = UserProfil.objects.all()
success_url         = reverse_lazy('dashboard/profil')
```

dashboard/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.UserDashboardTemplateView.as_view(), name='index'),
path('profil/<pk>', views.UserProfilUpdateView.as_view(), name='profil'),
```

]

got error : **raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'profil' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard/profil/(?P[^/]+)$']**

Comment: Your `forms` has a model?

Comment: yes sir, that forms has a model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem maybe i can got some documentation sir ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got The Answer,
im need two classess in forms.py, and call Account and UserProfile Model.

**dashboard/forms.py**

```
class UserAccountUpdateForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model   = Account
    fields  = ['full_name', 'email']

class UserProfilUpdateForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model           = UserProfil
    exclude         = ['user']
```

**dashboard/views.py**

```
class UserProfilUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
model               = UserProfil
u_form              = UserAccountUpdateForm
p_form              = UserProfilUpdateForm
template_name       = 'dashboard/profil.html'
success_url         = reverse_lazy('dashboard/profil')

def post(self, request):
    post_data   =   request.POST or None

    u_form  =   UserAccountUpdateForm(post_data, instance=request.user)
    p_form  =   UserProfilUpdateForm(post_data, instance=UserProfil.objects.get(user = request.user))

    if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
        u_form.save()
        p_form.save()

    context = self.get_context_data( u_form = u_form , p_form = p_form)

    return  self.render_to_response(context)

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```